# Is it possible to find the minimum map-able unit (MMU) after creating a map?

Tags: scale, digitizing, minimum-mapping-unit

I'm not very good with the GIS lingo so I apologise if this doesn't make too much sense!

Lets say I have just finished digitising the land cover of an aerial photograph and it's looking like the image below (credit to Richb)... However, upon completion I find out I need to specify my selected MMU and explain why I decided to use it.

How would I go about finding out the MMU for the project? Is it even possible to do so?

[image]

Comment: https://geozoneblog.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/resolution-vs-minimum-mapping-unit-size-does-matter/

Comment: "However, upon completion I find out I need to specify my selected MMU and explain why I decided to use it." - this sounds like a homework question

Comment: I am not aware that is is against site rules to ask for help with homework. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So as you were digitizing, was there any object that you decided was too small to be included, and others that were just big enough to be included? if so then subconsciously you may have defined a MMU.

Comment: Home work is Home work... the basic approach is "How can I do X" as I've tried a,b and c with package(s) x,y,z....but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mmu is based on many things. From the picture you have there it is not possible to tell and it should be done before you digitize a map.

Some hints how you can estimate the mmu:

what are the requirements? the smallest objects that need to be mapped and if they are for example needed as polygon or just as point

what are the technical boundaries? for example the resolution

what is reasonable? difficult to say sometimes but it is not reasonable to have a mmu much finer than the smallest object from your requirements

what is efficient? Sometimes you can argue against requirements when the time needed is far greater than anticipated (after a small test area is done)

Thats it... it depends on your given task and time available

Answer (score 0):

The minimum mapping units is almost never documented for a given .shp file. I have only ever seen it in very thorough metadata sets. Since you digitized the layer you will have to figure out the mmu on your own. I had a similar project in a GIS class I took years ago and I believe you are being asked to give the size of the smallest feature that you were able to digitized at the map scale you chose to perform the digitization at. So the answer would be the map scale and a measurement of the smallest visible feature.
A definition of mmu can be found at http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/minimum%20map%20unit. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my professional experience a minimum mappable unit should be decided before creating a map and not other way round! After all, the minimum mappable unit is one criterion  for map quality as dictated by the scale of mapping.